# What's the trick in Django's AuthenticationMiddleware

Tags: python, django

I'm reading the source code of Django and encountered a problem about `AuthenticationMiddleware`.

As the documentation said AuthenticationMiddleware

> Adds the user attribute (a instance of `User` model) to every incoming HttpRequest

But I can't understand how this is done in `AuthenticationMiddleware.process_request()`. As following code shows, `process_request` here just assign a `LazyUser()` to `request.__class__`, which has nothing to do with `User` model. And the `LazyUser.__get__()` seems very strange and make me confused a lot.

```
class LazyUser(object):
    def __get__(self, request, obj_type=None):
        if not hasattr(request, '_cached_user'):
            from django.contrib.auth import get_user
            request._cached_user = get_user(request)
        return request._cached_user

class AuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        assert hasattr(request, 'session'), "The Django authentication middleware requires session middleware to be installed. Edit your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting to insert 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'."
        request.__class__.user = LazyUser()
        return None
```

Briefly, I wonder what on earth happened behind the scene, when `AuthenticationMiddleware` hooks in processing `HttpRequest`??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `LazyUser` object is a [Python descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), i.e. an object that can dictate how itself is accessed through an instance of its parent class. (That's a mouthful.) Let me see if I can break it down for you:

```
# Having a LazyUser means we don't have to get the actual User object
# for each request before it's actually accessed.
class LazyUser(object):
    # Define the __get__ operation for the descripted object.
    # According to the docs, "descr.__get__(self, obj, type=None) --> value".
    # We don't need the type (obj_type) for anything, so don't mind that.
    def __get__(self, request, obj_type=None):
        # This particular request doesn't have a cached user?
        if not hasattr(request, '_cached_user'):
            # Then let's go get it!
            from django.contrib.auth import get_user
            # And save it to that "hidden" field.
            request._cached_user = get_user(request)
        # Okay, now we have it, so return it.
        return request._cached_user

class AuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    # This is done for every request...
    def process_request(self, request):
        # Sanity checking.
        assert hasattr(request, 'session'), "blah blah blah."
        # Put the descriptor in the class's dictionary. It can thus be
        # accessed by the class's instances with `.user`,  and that'll
        # trigger the above __get__ method, eventually returning an User, 
        # AnonymousUser, or what-have-you.
        # Come to think of it, this probably wouldn't have to be done 
        # every time, but the performance gain of checking whether we already
        # have an User attribute would be negligible, or maybe even negative.
        request.__class__.user = LazyUser()
        # We didn't mess with the request enough to have to return a
        # response, so return None.
        return None
```

Does that help at all? :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your very detailed answer! A follow-up question, what is the difference between `request.user = LazyUser()` and `request.__class__.user = LazyUser()`. I think the former is also ok, isn't it?

Comment: And, when we're accessing LazyUser by `request.user.username`, why `request` is passed to `__get__` as second parameter? Shouldn't it be `user` according to [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__): *while instance is the instance that the attribute was accessed through*?

Comment: @ColinZ: That's a tricky phrase in the docs. The **instance** in that case means the **request**, where the **LazyUser** is the **attribute** (called `user`, though the LazyUser wouldn't know).

Comment: Totally no idea...I guess I'd better head to some detailed reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

LazyUser ist just a wrapper, a lazy wrapper. The **get** method is one of Python's magic methods, which will be called, when die object is accesses. Thus the user is only determined, if and when it is actually used. This makes sense since this operation will trigger database calls and this should only happen, if the user is really required.

The LazyUser is assigned not to the request instance itself, but to the reqeust's instance class, which also makes it available to the instance. Why it is done this way I cannot tell.